# PySpark - numpy | pandas | matplotlib

Tags: pandas, numpy, matplotlib, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I already make some research to find the answer for my question but I ddin't find anything...

How can I use this labs in Pyspark:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Anyone have a article that ilustrate ao to use it?

I'm trying to save a dataframe to make some graphs like this (I see this code here):

```
data1 = pd.sc.textFile("TEXT").flatMap { line => line.split("\n") }.distinct()

freqMap = {}
for line in data1:
  for item in line:
    if not item in freqMap:
      freqMap[item] = {}

    for other_item in line:
      if not other_item in freqMap:
        freqMap[other_item] = {}

      freqMap[item][other_item] = freqMap[item].get(other_item, 0) + 1
      freqMap[other_item][item] = freqMap[other_item].get(item, 0) + 1

df = data1[freqMap].fillna(0)
print(df)

plt.pcolormesh(df, edgecolors='black')
plt.yticks(np.arange(0.5, len(df.index), 1), df.index)
plt.xticks(np.arange(0.5, len(df.columns), 1), df.columns)
plt.savefig('plot.png')
plt.savefig('plot.png')
```

Thanks!

Comment: It is not clear what you need.

Comment: @LostInOverflow sorry, just updated the question with my code

Comment: `.flatMap { line => line.split("\n") }` appears to be Scala.  And the nested for loops don't look like PySpark code either.  I suggest that you try simple tutorial for each module, then put them together.  Spark is distributed computing environment.   In order for matplotlib to draw graphs, you'd have to `.collect()` to get the data back to the driver node.

Comment: @John_Rodgers maybe off-topic, but have a look at pixiedust, no need for downsampling + interactive https://github.com/ibm-watson-data-lab/pixiedust